# If A is a Borel set in the real line and x is any real number, show that translate of A, defined by A + x = {y + x : y ∈ A} is also a Borel

Tags: probability-theory

If $A$ is a Borel set in the real line and $x$ is any real number, show that translate of $A$, defined by $A + x = \{y + x : y \in A\}$ is also a Borel set. Show that $−A = \{−y : y \in A\}$ is also a Borel set.

Comment: I suspect the reason for the down-vote is that this is phrased in a way suitable for assigning homework.  Under the circumstances, that makes people wonder if you copied a question without even understanding the question.  If you don't understand a question, you could say so ask here for an explanation of what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(y)=y-x$ is continuous and, in particular, Borel-measurable. Then,
$$
A+x=f^{-1}(A).
$$
Since $A$ is Borel-measurable, $A+x$ must also be Borel-measurable. The case with $-A$ can be dealt with similarly. I leave that to you.